# Set highcharts x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis, default-value

I'm having an issue with HighCharts where I have a lot of data, and would like to indicate the X-axis in "hours" instead of "minutes". So it only displays every 60 minutes as 1 hour. 
- Right now it display every 10 data in the X-axis. I need it to display every 60 instead.

On this link you can see a picture of what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ln2mkl0tb1444sp/xaxis.png?dl=0

How do I define the X-axis only to display every 60 “minutes” as 1 “hour”… 2 hours… 3 hours etc.

Comment: Just found the answer.

Use:
            xAxis: 
        {
            tickInterval: 2,
},

Comment: You can also use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) which allows to calculate ticks dynamically.